# cakePHP 2.x Custom Authentication

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So I am working with cakePHP 2.3 and I try to use different Frameworks when possible a) to keep my 41 Year old mind aware b) To make sure I use every tool in the shed for myself and my customer.

I have a personal SaaS app Im building and need to know the best way to add "where `site_id` =  2" to the authentication calls basically based on how they are viewing the app i.e. subdomain or domain sets a particular site_id in AppController.

I have looked for custom authentication but I havent seen anything that stood out. I also have a roles column & table which is comma delim I need to join in the auth request

Any good how to's or pointers would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just taking a shot in the dark here with limited info but i think this is somewhere around the woods of what your looking for.
Locate your cake build and navigate to /lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php

Locate:

```
public $settings = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password'
        ),
        'userModel' => 'User',
        'scope' => array(),
        'recursive' => 0,
        'contain' => null,
    );
```

and make your mods there.

Comment: /lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php have similar params I dont know which is taking precedence in the stretch so I recommend backing up each and doing a POE(Process of Elimination )